# LINQ query to select specific data

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to write the query that will return only the specific information that I need to display in the view.

I have the following code:

```
var companiesWithResponsibleUser = from company in ctx.Companies
   join user in ctx.Users on company.ResponsibleUserId equals user.Id
   group new { company, user } by company.Id into g
   select new
   {
       company = g.Select(t => t.company),
       user = g.Select(t => t.user)
   };
```

However this one returns the full data from both tables, which is very slow. I only need company name, address from company table and responsible user ID and full name from user table.

How can I rewrite this query so that it only populates these two objects with the data I want?

Comment: Have you tried limiting the output in projection by listing only the required properties (instead of getting both company and user)?

Comment: @Martin how do i do it? I'm quite new to writing queries

Comment: Just edit the Select part of the query like below,

Select new { CompanyName = g.First(t => t.company).Name, FullName = g.First(t => t.user).FullName }

Of course, I am assuming you have Name and FullName as valid props there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should help you:

```
var companiesWithResponsibleUser  = from company in ctx.Companies
       join user in ctx.Users on company.ResponsibleUserId equals user.Id
       group new { company, user } by company.Id into g
       select new
       {
           companyname = g.company.CompanyName
           address= g.company.Address,
           userid = g.user.UserId,
           fullname= g.user.FullName
       };
```

Please note that I haven't tested this.

Answer (score 1):

I am not so sure but you can try this:

```
var companiesWithResponsibleUser = (from company in ctx.Companies
                                               join user in ctx.Users on 
                                   company.ResponsibleUserId equals user.Id
                                   select company.CompanyName,company.Address,user.Userid,user.UserFullName).ToList();


var Res = (from x in companiesWithResponsibleUser
  group x by new
  {
      x.CompanyName,
      x.Userid
  } into g
  select new {g.key.CompanyName, g.Address,g.key.Userid,g.UserFullName}).ToList();
```

You can add this part if error occur `g.Address`

```
  x.CompanyName,
  x.Userid,
  x.Address
```

if field does not exists in `select` then user `g.key.Address`